# How do I make Windows switch Wifi connections when a limit is reached?

Tags: wireless-networking, backup, wireless-router, isp, autorun

My Internet service provider only allows me a cap of 30gb a month. It's a 4g LTE router which I connect to wirelessly. I also have another 3g wireless router as a backup.

Windows does not show "no internet Connection" once the limit is reached because the page notifying me the data bundle has been depleted is still accessible.

Is there any way to set Windows to switch to the backup automatically when the limit is reached?

Comment: I seriously doubt anyone would have ever created software to do this, and asking for software recommendations on this site is considered off topic.

Comment: Any answer to this would likely be dependent on the version of "windows" you are using. So, you might want to [edit] your question to include that information. Also, tell us what you've tried/researched on your own so far.